# How exactly I can calculate difficulty for a given share

Tags: go-ethereum, difficulty

Let's say I have a share for ethereum

```
BlockNumber = 1155545, 
hashNoNonce = ec31d253819762aaa186685e1eb743fc9b058b2e550539952e48abe63b0ad1c8
nonce = 4499658978045803798
```

What is the formula for difficulty?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suppose that the share depends on the number of "nonce submissions" that your node has sent to the mining pool. My understanding is that the mining pool divides the reward per block (-1% of pool fee) by the number of "nonce submissions" everybody submitted and sends you the proportional value of that reward. If I would be a pool owner, that's what I would do. The difficulty is not calculated per share, the share is your payoff from the block reward.

Comment: But share has some difficulty, right?

Comment: you run your node with much lower difficulty than the actual difficulty of the network, and submit all the `nonces` found, and the pool will check if your nonce is good enough to fit the network difficulty, if it does, then your submission is going to bring a win for the entire pool. So, it is the pool who decides which difficulty is good for you, they may use a dynamic difficulty to adjust it to your node, or have a static difficulty. No formula.

Comment: > " the pool will check if your nonce is good enough to fit the network difficulty,"
How? By calculating what?

Comment: they feed the `nonce` you provided into the hashimoto algorithm and the algorithm checks if the nonce is valid. Check this question, maybe it will help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/why-are-there-no-leading-zeroes-in-ethereum-block-hash